# "The key to/of the door"

Tags: differences, prepositions, to-of

I would like to know what the difference between "the key *to* the door" and "the the key *of* the door", or between "the servant *to* the master" and "the servant *of* the master" is.

Answer (score 2):

English seems to have a preference for *to* or *for* when referring to an item for "operating" something. Hence:

> the key to/for the door
>
> the switch to/for the hall lights
>
> the catch to/for the window

On the other hand, 'of' is used more when you're naming a component part of something; sometimes either 'of' or 'to/for' is possible, depending on whether you're just naming a part of something or implying its intended use:

> the leg of the table
>
> the door of/to/for the fridge
>
> the ingredients of/to/for this soup

When identifying a part of something, English also permits other prepositions denoting location:

> the handle *on* the fridge
>
> the largest collection *in* the world

Various other languages tend to use the equivalent of 'of' in many of these cases: i.e. they have less of a distinction between naming the 'utility' vs 'existence' vs 'identification/location' of a component of something.

Answer (score 0):

In English we speak of the key *to* the door, not the key *of* the door.

With respect to servants, you can perform as the *servant to the master* or be the *servant of the master*. You would use *to* when describing the act of performing as a servant, and *of* when describing the state of being a servant.

Comment: This can be surprising for who speaks English as second language, but in English it is _key to the door_, while other languages would say the equivalent of _key of the door_.

Comment: Plus, one rarely hears *key to the door* even in regular conversation. We simply say *key* or *key to [name of building or room]*. E.g. "Where's the key?" "I need the key to the library" "Where's the key to the locker room?" Most times, we tend to form compound nouns with *key*, as in: "gym keys", "car key[s]", "garage key", "cellar key", etc.